# Запрет блокировки экрана

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Как в Windows Pnone 8.1 сделать, чтобы во время исполнения приложения телефон не блокировался?

На просторах интернета нашел решение для WP8, что должно помочь

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

но для WP8.1 это не работает.

Comment: по-моему, вопрос не попадает в тематику сайта: [help/on-topic]

Comment: "Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:...к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается с помощью [DisplayRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx), ([см. также](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653968/how-to-prevent-lockscreen-in-a-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app)):

```
Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest req = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
req.RequestActive();
```